# Redirect to a different URL on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send a post request which in turn is going to redirect to a different url when a user clicks the refresh button in the website

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     console.log(`Page Reloaded`)
     function redirectPost(url, data,name) {

         var form = document.createElement('form');
         document.body.appendChild(form);
         form.method = 'post';
         form.action = url;
         var input = document.createElement('input');
         input.type = 'hidden';
         input.name = name;
         input.value = data;
         form.appendChild(input);  
         form.submit();
     }

   redirectPost("/incompleteOrder",$("#orderNumber").val(),"orderNumber")

});
```

This code should simulate sending a post request using a form during a page reload. In my backend Nodejs code I have a post url which basically does some database input and redirects to a get url to render the same page where refresh was clicked.

However the post request to `/incompleteOrder` does not even fire in my backend even though the console message saying the page reload flashes for a few seconds. It completely ignores my form submit.

Comment: you'll probably need to `preventDefault` here.. why are you attaching this event to beforeunload and not on the button the user is supposedly clicking?  you may be violating a security rule here by redirecting without it being user invoked in this manner.  Typically, you would alert the user with a dialog in this fashion and perform the redirect on the user's interaction with that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending ajax request instead?

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/incompleteOrder',
        data: {
            orderNumber: $("#orderNumber").val()
        },
        success: function () {
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: For some reason this does fire the post route which then fires my get route. But the issue is the get route because of the refresh fires before the get route I want. I tried `e.preventDefault()` but it did not help